# Best wasy to build redis cache for all pages in shop - laravel 7

Tags: laravel, redis

in my customer shop i use redis as cache driver. It is used to store parts of page that needs a lot of queries - like product listing, product view, category view. (middle part of pages rendered). Here is small sample of code **(it's cutted!)**:

```
class CategoryController extends BaseController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
            return View('themes.frontend.pages.category.index', [
                'content' => $this->getCategoryCache($request)
            ]);
        
    }

    private function getCategoryCache($request)
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->getCacheKey($params), 296000, function () use ($request) {
              return View('themes.frontend.pages.category.index_content')->render();
    }
}
```

So when user visits category it's calling index that's call for content from other functions. In this example  getCategoryCache search for cache key and returns it. Value of cache is html view rendered and stored in redis. If cache key not exists it's calling database for data and renders view then store in redis.

Questions is: how to generate all cache keys for "for example" category pages in shop?
Reason for question - when i need sometimes to dump whole cache it take time to rebuild it because page must be visited to get redis filled up. So first user won't 'feel' redis speed benefit.

I was thinking about calling db for all categories and foreach them; then custom function will generate keys. Tricky part - there is 3500 categories plus 25k products that need generating.

Is there some reasonable way to do it?

Many thanks for help!
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you know which categories and products are popular you could make artisan command to cache just popular ones.